# Selectively update lines in a file based on their content

Tags: powershell, select-string

I am new to Powershell scripting and i have gone through the powershell tutorial to complete my current script requirement.

I am trying to add exclamatory mark to the line by matching the pattern. I am having similar test.default file as below

```
"/AgentSetup/__type__"

"/AgentSetup/__name__"

"/AgentSetup/preloadedKs"

"/AgentSetup/preloadedKMsArch"

"/AgentSetup/loadOnlyPreloadedKMs"
```

More lines like this in the file

So here i am trying add exclamatory mark to the starting of the line by matching for example if i search for "/AgentSetup/preloadedKs" = { REPLACE="" }, then in the file it should look like

```
"/AgentSetup/__type__"

"/AgentSetup/__name__"

"/AgentSetup/preloadedKs"

!"/AgentSetup/defaultAccount"

"/AgentSetup/preloadedKMsArch"

"/AgentSetup/loadOnlyPreloadedKMs"
```

I tried below commands to achieve this but not succeefull

```
$TEST = "C:\Asset\config.default"
$Pattern = "/AgentSetup/defaultAccount"
$var = "!" + (Select-String -Path $TEST -pattern $Pattern | Out-String)
$var
$var + (Get-Content $TEST -Raw) | Set-Content $TEST
```

The above commands is not just adding exclamatory mark but adding dublicate entry in the file like this:

```
!

test.default:103:"/AgentSetup/defaultAccount"
```

I have gone through powershell `Add-Content` and `Select-String` tutorial even I searched `Get-Content`. Please guide me to the right direction so i can achieve this it would be helpful.

Comment: here's the steps i would use ... [1] read the file into a $Var [2] iterate thru that collection [3] match on the desired string [4] if no match, send string out to a NEW file with `Add-Content` [5] if match found, edit string & send to the same file

Comment: Step (5) you mean to say concatenate currently reading concatenation will update if any success

Comment: edit means to change. [*grin*] if you choose to do that with concatenation, then it is still an edit. ///// good luck!

Comment: replace `(Select-String -Path $TEST -pattern $Pattern | Out-String)` with `(Select-String -Path $TEST -pattern $Pattern).Line`

Comment: Thanks Mathias for your kind suggestion and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach:

- As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) suggests in a comment, instead of piping the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) call's output to `Out-String`<sup>[1]</sup>, access the `.Line` property on the result, which contains the matched line only.

  - **`Select-String` doesn't output *strings***, it outputs [*match-information* objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) whose **`.Line` property** contains the matching line (string).
  - Note that there's a green-lit feature suggestion - not yet implemented as of Windows PowerShell Core 6.2.0 - to allow `Select-String` to emit strings directly, using the proposed `-Raw` switch - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7713
- You're simply prepending the modified copy of the line of interest to your output, which means that **the *original, unmodified* line remains part of the rewritten file**.

I suggest using a different approach altogether, based on the `-replace` operator, which makes for a solution that is both more concise and faster:

```
(Get-Content $TEST) -replace '^"/AgentSetup/preloadedKs"$', '!$&' | Set-Content $TEST
```

- `^` matches the start of each input string and `$` the end, so that only lines that contain nothing but the search string are matched.
- `$&` is a placeholder for what was matched, i.e. the original line in this case; for more about `-replace` and these placeholders, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

Note that this updates the line in its original position.

Enclosing the `Get-Content` call in `(...)` ensures that the file is read in full up front, which enables writing back to the same file with `Set-Content` in the same pipeline; while this is convenient, it bears a slight risk of data loss, if writing back to the file is interrupted.

---

<sup>[1] The purpose of `Out-String` is to create string representations of objects *as they would print to the console*, which is generally not suitable for programmatic processing; even using `.ToString()` on the match-info objects (or placing them inside `"..."`) won't work as intended in this case, because the resulting representation includes the input filename too.</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Alex; my pleasure.